# HLSL Debugger VS2013, Source code not available?

Tags: debugging, shader, hlsl

I'm having an issue with "Source Not Available" when trying to run the HLSL debugger. Is there a way of attaching a hlsl source? If not is there a special location where the source file needs to be in?

The big problem is that I'm not getting anything drawn and as far as I can see is that after the vertex shader everything is discarded.

Comment: Did you compile your shaders with Debug Information (/Zi)?

Comment: Yeah I did not sure what else to do with it really